# Regex to remove strings in notepad++ that contains certain amount of numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++

If I have the following lines, how to

1. leave only 10-11 digits long strings that starts with "04" or "05". Don't remove empty lines.

```
0409999999  012345678
012345678   0409999999
023456789   034566  0455555555
012345678   012345678
0299999999
```

so the lines above should then look like:

```
0409999999
0409999999
0455555555
```

Comment: It may not be possible to do this via a single regex replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest pattern

```
\b\d{0,9}|0[45]\d{8,9}\b
```

Explanation:

`\b` - word boundary

`\d{0,9}` - match up to 9 digits

`|` - alternation

`0` - match 0 literally

`[45]` - match 4 or 5

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oJu2iu/1)

**EDIT**

After update you can use `[ \t]*(?!0[45]\d{8,9})\b\d+[ \t]*`

The difference here is that it uses negative lookahead to assure that what is ahead is not 10-11 digit number starting with 04 or 05.

`[ \t]` are used to trim space and tabs.

Then you just need to replace it with empty string.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't work as I was hoping. I've modified my question to make it hopefully more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(?!04|05)\d{1,9}\b|\b\d{10,11}\b
```